# Cannot connect to new user just created on oracle on docker (ORA-01017)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I'm trying to use Oracle 12c on Ubuntu 18 to study for my work.

For it, I'm using docker-compose file I used to create in other PCs.

```
version: '2'
services:
 database:
   image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
   volumes:
     - ./data:/ORCL # persistent oracle database data.
   ports:
     - 1529:1521
     - 8082:8080
     - 5500:5500
```

After install, I can login as sysadmin and I enter those codes below to create a user.

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = ORCLPDB1;
CREATE USER BUS IDENTIFIED BY DEMO_PASS;
GRANT CONNECT TO BUS;
```

and then, I try to connect to it.

```
sqlplus BUS/DEMO_PASS@localhost:1529/ORCLCDB.localdomain
```

I want to login as could in other PCs but instead of this, I'm getting this error.

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Comment: I've got this message when starts docker

```terminal
 # == Add below entries to your tnsnames.ora to access this database server ==    
 #  from external host     
 ORCLCDB=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip-address>)(PORT=<port>))  
     (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLCDB.localdomain)))       
 ORCLPDB1=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip-address>)(PORT=<port>))  
     (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLPDB1.localdomain)))       
 ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to the wrong database - ORCLDB.localdomain is the service for the CONTAINER database.

You did a, alter session set container = ORCLPDB1 => that is the database you want to connect to, so try

```
sqlplus BUS/DEMO_PASS@localhost:1529/ORCLPDB1
```

Also if you're looking for a more user friendly CLI for Oracle, we build [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html).

Comment: thanks to responding.    
  
I tryied the command you wrote and I got error below.  
```terminal
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
```
  
this CLI looks good.  
I'll try this one

Comment: Lsnrctl status - grab the service name for your pdb, should be there

Comment: Ok so sqlplus BUS/DEMO_PASS@localhost:1529/SERVICE_NAME=ORCLPDB1.localdomain

Comment: No... sqlplus BUS/DEMO_PASS@//localhost:1529/ORCLPDB1.localdomain

Comment: thanks guys. I could login with `sqlplus BUS/DEMO_PASS@//localhost:1529/ORCLPDB1.localdomain`  
But I still don't know why I could not login with same command I used in other PCs...

Comment: @MarcioKojiCarvalho other pcs, that would not have worked, you're connecting to localhost, which is the local machine, if it worked on another pc, that's a whole other database they are connecting to

Answer (score 11):

You have to create user for connection.

Look my sample here:

```
docker container run -d -h localdomain --name odbc2 -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -e DB_SID=ORCLCDB -e DB_PDB=ORCLPDB1 -e DB_DOMAIN=localdomain store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim

docker exec -it odbc2 bash -c "source /home/oracle/.bashrc; sqlplus /nolog"


connect sys as sysdba;
-- password  'Oradoc_db1'
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
create user dummy identified by dummy;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO dummy;
create table Docker (id int,name varchar2(20));
```

Connection info:

```
SID:ORCLCDB
PORT:1521
username: dummy
password: dummy
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCLCDB
```